# 2 sensor orientation to rotate normalised 3d vector to reference vector

Tags: vectors

I'm trying to understand the implementation of accelerometer and magnetometer as an orientation device.

If I make some assumptions that gravity is uniform and no external acceleration occurs I have 1 known vector. G=1 (Gx=0,Gy=0,Gz=1)

My magnetometer gives another vector Magnetic north. assuming corrected for Hard and Soft Iron offsets and normalised. M=1 (Mx=0,My=1,Mz=0)

It is the cross product of these two vectors that gives me my 3rd vector (magnetic east?) which is perpendicular to both previous vectors.  This I understand but I don't understand how to create a value for this from my 2 readings.  in a formula sense what combination of Gx/Gy/Gz || Mx/My/Mz = Ex/Ey/Ez

all sensor readings are normalized so the vector would represent -1 \ 1 as min and max values and essentially represents points around a sphere.

My G should allow me to form a rotation matrix around X and Y axis.
My M should allow me to forma a rotation matrix around X and Z axis
My E should allow me to form a rotation matrix around Y and Z axis.
allowing for cross referencing.

does sound like reasonable mathematical approach to this problem.  I have read many articles online which all seem to jump straight to C+ coding which I'm not savvy with so I am trying to understand the mathematics so I can work out the implementation.

Thank you.  apologies if it is a done question before but I can't find a clear solution or answer that makes sense.  my Maths understand used to be much better that it is now, but even so matrixes etc were not something I studied at A level physics or O level Maths.  I'm a surgeon now, so neither plays an ongoing role in my work.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at it from a different perspective. (No pun intended.) But first, some basic vector algebra:
Let
$$\bbox{\vec{a} = \left[\begin{matrix} a_x \\ a_y \\ a_z \end{matrix}\right]}
, \quad
\bbox{\vec{b} = \left[\begin{matrix} b_x \\ b_y \\ b_z \end{matrix}\right]}
, \quad
\bbox{\vec{c} = \left[\begin{matrix} c_x \\ c_y \\ c_z \end{matrix}\right]}
, \quad
\bbox{\mathbf{R} = \left[\begin{matrix}
r_{11} & r_{12} & r_{13} \\
r_{21} & r_{22} & r_{23} \\
r_{31} & r_{32} & r_{33} \end{matrix}\right]}$$
Vector dot product is
$$\bbox{\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}} = \bbox{ a_x b_x + a_y b_y + a_z b_z }$$
Length or norm is
$$\left\lVert\vec{a}\right\rVert = \sqrt{\vec{a} \cdot \vec{a}} = \sqrt{ a_x^2 + a_y^2 + a_z^2}$$
Vector cross product is
$$\bbox{\vec{c} = \vec{a} \times \vec{b}} \quad \iff \quad
\bbox{\begin{cases}
c_x = a_y \, b_z - a_z \, b_y \\
c_y = a_z \, b_x - a_x \, b_z \\
c_z = a_x \, b_y - a_y \, b_x \\
\end{cases}}$$
Matrix-vector product is
$$\bbox{\vec{c} = \mathbf{R}\vec{a}} \quad \iff \quad
\bbox{\begin{cases}
c_x = r_{11} \, a_x \; + \; r_{12} \, a_y \; + \; r_{13} \, a_z \\
c_y = r_{21} \, a_x \; + \; r_{22} \, a_y \; + \; r_{23} \, a_z \\
c_z = r_{31} \, a_x \; + \; r_{32} \, a_y \; + \; r_{33} \, a_z \\
\end{cases}}$$

---

Let's say your device tells you that the acceleration vector $\vec{G}$ and magnetic north vector $\vec{N}$ are
$$\bbox{\vec{G} = \left[ \begin{matrix} G_x \\ G_y \\ G_z \end{matrix} \right ]}
, \quad
\bbox{\vec{N} = \left[ \begin{matrix} N_x \\ N_y \\ N_z \end{matrix} \right ]}$$
What we want to do first, is to use these to generate a set of orthogonal basis vectors $\vec{e}_1$, $\vec{e}_2$, and $\vec{e}_3$, that we can then normalize (scale) to unit length orthonormal basis vectors $\hat{e}_1$, $\hat{e}_2$, and $\hat{e}_3$.

The easiest method is to use the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram-Schmidt_process): we pick the one we trust most, and take the part of the second vector that is perpendicular to the first. The third is their vector cross product.

Let's say we trust the acceleration most, so we choose
$$\hat{e}_1 = \left[\begin{matrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \\ z_1 \end{matrix}\right] = \frac{\vec{G}}{\left\lVert\vec{G}\right\rVert} =
\left[\begin{matrix}
\frac{G_x}{\sqrt{G_x^2 + G_y^2 + G_z^2}} \\
\frac{G_y}{\sqrt{G_x^2 + G_y^2 + G_z^2}} \\
\frac{G_z}{\sqrt{G_x^2 + G_y^2 + G_z^2}} \\
\end{matrix}\right]$$
The second is magnetic north, but we only want the part that is perpendicular to $\hat{e}_1$:
$$\vec{n} = \bbox{\left[\begin{matrix} n_x \\ n_y \\ n_z \end{matrix} \right]} = \vec{N} - \hat{e}_1 \left ( \hat{e}_1 \cdot \vec{N} \right )$$
i.e.
$$\begin{cases}
n_x = N_x - x_1 ( x_1 N_x + y_1 N_y + z_1 N_z ) \\
n_y = N_y - y_1 ( x_1 N_x + y_1 N_y + z_1 N_z ) \\
n_z = N_z - z_1 ( x_1 N_x + y_1 N_y + z_1 N_z ) \\
\end{cases}$$
with the second orthonormal basis vector being
$$\hat{e}_2 = \bbox{\left[\begin{matrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \\ z_2
\end{matrix}\right]} = \frac{\vec{e}_2}{\left\lVert\vec{e}_2\right\rVert} = \bbox{\left [ \begin{matrix}
\frac{n_x}{\sqrt{n_x^2 + n_y^2 + n_z^2}} \\
\frac{n_y}{\sqrt{n_x^2 + n_y^2 + n_z^2}} \\
\frac{n_z}{\sqrt{n_x^2 + n_y^2 + n_z^2}} \end{matrix}\right]}$$
The third orthonormal basis vector is the vector cross product of the first two,
$$\hat{e}_3 = \bbox{\left[\begin{matrix} x_3 \\ y_3 \\ z_3 \end{matrix}\right]} = \hat{e}_1 \times \hat{e}_2$$
i.e.
$$\begin{cases}
x_3 = x_2 \, y_3 - x_3 \, y_2 \\
y_3 = y_2 \, x_3 - x_2 \, y_3 \\
z_3 = x_1 \, y_2 - x_1 \, y_2 \\
\end{cases}$$
These three give us the orthonormal basis vectors we need.

If we want $\vec{G}$ to correspond to the positive $z$ axis, and $\vec{N}$ to the positive $y$ axis, then the matrix that rotates that coordinate system to the current orientation measured is $\mathbf{M}$,
$$\mathbf{M} = \bbox{\bigr[\begin{matrix} \vec{e}_3 & \vec{e}_2 & \vec{e}_1 \end{matrix}\bigr]} = \bbox{\left[\begin{matrix}
x_3 & x_2 & x_1 \\
y_3 & y_2 & y_1 \\
z_3 & z_2 & z_1 \end{matrix}\right]}$$
Because the three column vectors of $\mathbf{M}$ are orthogonal, $\mathbf{M}$ is [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) as well, and its inverse is its transpose.

This means that to rotate the current orientation so that $\vec{G}$ is on the positive $z$ axis, and $\vec{N}$ on the positive $y$ axis, we need to apply matrix
$$\mathbf{M}^{-1} = \mathbf{M}^T = \bbox{\left[\begin{matrix}
x_3 & y_3 & z_3 \\
x_2 & y_2 & z_2 \\
x_1 & y_1 & z_1 \end{matrix}\right]}$$

You do not want to use Euler or Tait-Bryan angles. They are nasty. They are actually a large family of related definitions, depending on the order of the axes being rotated.  Instead, just use the above matrices directly.

Let's say you have a vector $\vec{a}$ that points to say east, i.e. $\vec{a} = (-1, 0, 0)$.  In the coordinate system defined by the sensor readings, east is $\vec{c} = \mathbf{M}\vec{a}$. (You could then say draw an arrow on a 2D screen using just $(c_x , c_y)$.)

Inversely, if we want to know what a vector $\vec{c}$ in current coordinate system defined by the sensor readings is in the world coordinate system, we do $\vec{a} = \mathbf{M}^T \vec{c}$.

There is usually no need for any kind of axis-angle representation, but if you do need it, you can convert the matrix (either one) to other representations using the formulae outlined in the Wikipedia [Rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) article.

Comment: ok, that is actually surprisingly clear - I think.

Comment: ok, that is actually surprisingly clear - I think.  hm, can't seem to enter for new line so will be continuous text apologies.  following these for M I get (-1,0,0 / 0,1,0 / 0,0,1) sorry I can't make that come as a picture. M equates to what my reference frame would be with the device perfectly orientated to gravity through Z and Magnetic north through Y and my cross product e3 through X axis.  if I now rotate my device the vector values would change say I turn it 90 clockwise around Z. M1= (0,1,0 / -1,0,0 / 0,0,1).

Comment: so then using the formula I can output this as a quat or euler angles or whatever just from vector values.  does it matter that Magnetic north is not 100% perpendicular to gravity or is that what the little n calculation factors out?  in Australia with have declination of about 10 degrees

Comment: @IanBloomfield: (Formatting guide is [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)). Yes, that's it for $\mathbf{M}$. The $\vec{n}$ calculation does exactly that, factors out the non-perpendicular part.

Comment: Great so I'm actually really happy I've created a 3x3 matrix of floats and as I rotate my device it gives me outputs -1 / 1 which moves through the correct axis so in my head and on paper I could calculate the exact orientation using this which is what I want.

Comment: When I'm at work I'll write out my understanding of your formulas as an answer.  Can I get your opinion on how best to represent this data, my context is the device is mounted one on the forearm and one across the knuckles.  I want to use the orientation to demonstrate the movement in these joints. Is there a way to calculate a dot point say 10cm from 0,0,0 and calculate coordinates using matrix, that would represent the location of the device compared to the wrist which is really the rotation I'm mapping, it should then plot spherical movement, flexion/extension, abduction/adduction

Comment: That was why I thought to calculate roll/pitch/yaw from these readings, but I think actually there is more data stored in the matrix, plus it reduces the calculations my software had to do

Comment: @IanBloomfield: Let's say $\mathbf{M}_A$ is on the forearm, and $\mathbf{M}_B$ is on the back of the hand, say on the metacarpophlhlh.. knuckles. We can extract the wrist joint deflection angle (say positive if down, negative if up), the rotation of the palm (in the plane of the palm, "left to right"), and the ulna-radius rotation (around the axis of the forearm). I'd use a graphical display to display these three, but I'd get a surgeon and a graphic UX specialist to talk exactly how; probably as three separate images with the angles shown. Similarly, ...

Comment: if you have additional acceleration sensors in the fingers (between the joints, and after the third joint), say $\mathbf{M}_1$, $\mathbf{M}_2$, and $\mathbf{M}_3$, we can use each sequential pair to find out the angle in the joint between the two.  (Lots of microcontrollers can handle many of those sensor chips, so you could probably analyse each finger joint separately.)

Comment: @IanBloomfield: The "trick" is that we can multiply matrices to apply consecutive rotations. The first rotation goes rightmost, and last rotation leftmost, so rotating by $\mathbf{M}_B^T$ and then by $\mathbf{M}_A$ is simply $\mathbf{M}_A\mathbf{M}_B^T$.  For a pair of sensors, if $\vec{a}_A$ and $\vec{a}_B$ are "forwards" (towards fingers in the rest pose) in the sensor coordinate system, then in the global coordinate system, the measured directions are $\mathbf{M}_A^T\vec{a}_A$ and $\mathbf{M}_B^T\vec{a}_B$. Their relation to each other describes the deflection.

Comment: If you want, you can contact me via email (shown on my homepage, linked to from my profile) in case you need more detailed information, but cannot provide further details here in public due to e.g. confidentiality reasons.  I like the idea of a surgeon checking out these ubiquitous microcontrollers and sensors (that I myself play with) to see if they can be used to make tools that help with diagnostics; I wouldn't mind giving free math/physics advice to one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Didn’t understand your context completely but just to aid the computations putting across the formulas

cross product of two vectors in Cartesian form is given by [image: cross product]

Rotation matrices are as follows:
[image: rotation matrix]

An example is shown below To multiply z component by 90 deg 
[image: Rotate z component]

Comment: Thank you so to understand this the letters I, j, k are the XYZ components of my new vector? so in y normalized example would be -1,0,0 this would reflect a vector to the west.

Comment: I think in essence what it seems like I am trying to understand is the direction cosine matrix.  I thought the rotation is calculated by the difference in the vector - ie. as my body moves in relation to the fixed reference frame is the same as assuming the body remains still but the fixed reference frame rotates. so to obtain the rotation can that be calculated from the difference in the vectors or do I use my gyroscope to know how much I've rotated then compare that to what my vector should be? or is there a reverse calculation somewhere

Comment: So I constructed a 3x3 matrix with float values using the outputs normalized from my 3 sensors. can I check a few outputs 90 roll (0,0,1 / 0,1,0 / 1,0,0) then return to reference -90 pitch (nosedive) ( -1,0,0 / 0,0,-1 \ 0,1,0) I'll do some combination readings of various angles.  so then if I construct another 3x3 matrix using the gyroscope - do I have to create a 3x3 matrix for each angle or is there a way to create it all in 1 3x3 matrix combining the 3 axis rotations using deltaT*angular velocity?